# NFC enableForegroundDispatch to handle Beam within activity

Tags: android, nfc, intentfilter, ndef, android-beam

the app i'm working on ought to receive a beam and then call the processIntent(intent) function from onResume. the problem i'm having is that when it receives the beam, it opens a completely new instance of the app instead of just staying within the activity (i've already called enableForegroundDispatch).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "No NFC on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // Create a PendingIntent object so the Android system can populate it with the details of the tag when it is scanned.
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    // Declare intent filters to handle the intents that the developer wants to intercept.
    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try {
        ndef.addDataType("application/com.sample.mime/string");
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        Log.wtf("mimeexception", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef};

... ...
}

public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  // Enable the foreground dispatch when the Activity regains focus.
  NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this).enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, null);

  if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        processIntent(getIntent());
  }
}

public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  // Disable the foreground dispatch when the Activity loses focus.
  NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this).disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

void processIntent(Intent intent){
    // do stuff
}
```

and here's the activity from the manifest

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.app.opensthisonebutshouldnt"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
        android:name="com.example.app.shouldopenthisone"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_invoice"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />\
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />\
            <data android:mimeType="application/com.example.nfctest/invoice" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

thanks for the input

Comment: Better to Override onNewIntent() If your activity is opened at that situtation it will be called..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `application/com.sample.mime/string` (used in `ndef.addDataType(...);`) does not look like a valid MIME type. Are you sure that you are Beaming this type? Even if you do, I'm not sure that Android will be able to process it. A valid MIME type that comes close to yours would be `application/com.sample.mime` (without the `/string` part). The same applies to the `/invoice` part of `application/com.example.nfctest/invoice`.
2. If your foreground dispatch intent filter does not match the *first record* of the Beamed NDEF message, your app may receive NFC events according to intent filters in your manifest. Note that `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filters only match the *first record* of an NDEF message.
3. If the Beamed message contains an AAR (Android Application Record) and none of your NFC-related intent filters matches the *first record* of the Beamed NDEF message, the first activity declared in your manifest that has an intent filter for actuion `MAIN`with category `LAUNCHER` will be started. **This seems to happen in your case.** So double check that your foreground dispatch actually matches the incoming NDEF message. Otherwise your activity may be re-launched according to the definitions in your app manifest.
4. Checking `getIntent()` in `onResume()` will only check the intent currently associated with your activity (i.e. the intent that initially started your activity or that has been registered using `setIntent(...)`) when your activity is *resumed*. However, events from the foreground dispatch that you registered will arrive in your activity's `onNewIntent()` method. So you need to override that method and process the NFC event there:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           processIntent(intent);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: that was it, the MIME type was wrong so it wasn't being caught correctly.